# invoking lodash _.bind() in the same way as jQuery.proxy()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, proxy, bind, lodash

As far as I can infer from the [Lodash documentation](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#bind), `_.bind(func, thisArg, [partials])` simply returns a version of `func` where the scope of `this` is bound to whatever you pass in to `thisArg`. However, you then need to invoke that function seperately, ie:

```
var boundFunction = _.bind(aFunction, aThisTarget);
boundFunction();
```

Is there a way to use `_.bind()` or a different function in lodash in the same manner that one can use jQuery's `.proxy()`, in that it immediately invokes the function with the passed in scope?

I don't need/want to save the found function to a variable, as it's part of a callback. I just want to fire a function with a different scope (immediately). IE:

```
this.loadScripts(function() {
    // do something   
}, $.proxy(this, 'doSomethingElse', 'params') );
```

Comment: `jQuery.proxy` doesn't immediately invokes function, it returns same function with bound context, just like lodash. Anyway you can write smth like this: `_.bind(foo, context)()`;

Comment: hm. If that's the case, then why is $.proxy getting invoked automatically for me, yet if I swap it out with `_.bind()` it's not? Just trying to figure out what's up :)

Comment: idk, can you demonstrate this case with some fiddle or mvce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LoDash's `_.bind` is an **early binding**. It takes *function object* and context to bind it to.

jQuery `$.proxy` (in your code) is **late binding**, it takes *key* (not a function itself, but function's name) and context. LoDash has late binding too: [_.bindKey](https://lodash.com/docs#bindKey).

The main difference is that late binding is lazy: it allows to bind function to object even if yet there's no actual function:

```js
var context = {}
var myMethod = _.bindKey(context, 'myMethod') // object is still empty
context.myMethod = function () { console.log('context:', this); }
myMethod() // will output proper context
```

It also allows not to duplicate context name in code :)

```js
// bind
_.bind(context.myMethod, context)
//     ^ 1               ^ 2

// bindKey
_.bindKey(context, 'myMethod')
//        ^ 1
```

Early binding, on the other hand, is more explicit, since it requires actual function to bind, not a key.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [method()](https://lodash.com/docs#method):

```
this.loadScripts(function() {

}, _.method(this, 'doSomethingElse', 'params'));
```